# openui5 sdk test suite page fails with response error 404

Tags: sapui5

Using either locally installed openui5-sdk-1.18.10 or here https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#resources/testsuite/welcome.html, when trying to access the testsuite, the response is HTTP Status 404 - Resource could not be found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the referenced link is currently invalid. Try the following instead:

**SAPUI5:**

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/testsuite

**OpenUI5:**

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/testsuite